# How can I save a Secret in Github with an empty value?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Secret that *could* have a value, but currently is blank. The Secrets interface in Github requires a value to save. Is there any way to save it with no value?

Comment: Potentially with the GitHub CLI using `gh secret set <name>` and then entering nothing; I was able to create the secret, but I'm not sure if it's truly empty or consists of a single newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Secrets cannot be empty. To workaround this use a boolean `workflow_dispatch` flag.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      is-empty-passphrase:
        type: boolean
        description: "Use empty password"
        default: true

jobs:
  use-empty-or-valid-passphrase:
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Is empty passphrase
        if: inputs.is-empty-passphrase
        echo "Login with empty passphrase"

      - name: Is valid passphrase
        if: ${{ !inputs.is-empty-passphrase }}
        echo "Login with valid passphrase. Use secrets context"
```